# Google End to end encryption for node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, end-to-end

I am working on something in nodejs, I am looking to implement something using

> https://github.com/google/end-to-end

But when i get compiled version,It doesn't seems to work on nodejs,But It does work on browsers

Is there is any nodeJs implementation of

> https://github.com/google/end-to-end

available ?

Comment: You mean you're trying to run a browser extension from a node.js server?

Comment: Yes, Is there is any way to do it.?

Comment: I don't think so...? It doesn't seem likely (to run all or part of the extension's endpoints from a server simply by putting the code on the server). Maybe someone around here is more clever than me, though.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks for your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way for you to use it in nodejs. It's a bit of a hack, but doable by loading it using closure way.

First build it so it generates a deps.js

```
cd end-to-end;
./do.sh build_library
```

Then you can override the import function to do the job of loading the library.

```
require('./lib/closure-library/closure/goog/bootstrap/nodejs.js')

global.CLOSURE_IMPORT_SCRIPT = function(src) {
  var E2E_PATH = './';
  var CLOSURE_SOURCE = './lib/closure-library/closure/goog/';
  try {
    require(CLOSURE_SOURCE + src);
  } catch (err) {
    require(E2E_PATH + src);
  }
  return true;
}

require('./build/deps.js');
goog.require('e2e.openpgp.asciiArmor');

console.log(e2e.openpgp.asciiArmor.encode('MESSAGE', e2e.stringToByteArray('test')));
```

---

Update: I add a package to do this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/e2enode

Comment: This is just working Fine,Special  Thanks for package